# Bullets are Not Visible, Will Not Remove From Screen After Removal

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pygame, pycharm

Here is my gaming code:

This is my entire piece of code. Why are my bullets not appearing on the screen when I fire them and
why does the bullets are still on the screen when I remove them (see lines 242 through 250)? If you have time, can you tell me why my game is lagging since I first start my game? Thank you for your help! (Already answered by another user)

```
    class Fire_User(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, image_file):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    #Move function#
        def update(self):
            self.rect.x -= 10

#Class for the player 1 to be able to fire projectiles(Steve's head from Minecraft) at player 2#
    class Fire_Comp(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
       def __init__(self, image_file):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #Move function#
       def update(self):
            self.rect.x += 10
```

And the Pygame events that shoot the bullet:

```
elif event.key == K_LSHIFT:
    bullet = Fire_User('bomb_user.jpg')
    bullet.rect.x = my_ball.rect.x + 10
    bullet.rect.y = my_ball.rect.y
    fired = 1
    bulletGroup.add(bullet)
elif event.key == K_RSHIFT:
    otherBullet = Fire_Comp('steve.png')
    otherBullet.rect.x = dad.rect.x - 10
    otherBullet.rect.y = dad.rect.y
    fired = 1
    otherBulletGroup.add(otherBullet)
```

**Update:**
I am trying to blit my pictures (the bullets) onto the screen. It gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/PyCharm_Tony/Hero's_War.py", line 273, in <module>
    screen.blit(bullet.image, bullet.rect)
NameError: name 'bullet' is not defined
```

Why is this happening? I have edited my program. Oh, running the code snippet will only load my code in a sentence (very long).

Answer (score 1):

The initial delay in starting the game is because of the statement

```
pygame.time.delay(1000)
```

Remove it or comment it to remove lag.

Now, instead of doing:

```
bullet = Fire_User()
otherBullet = Fire_Comp()
```

Create the instances at every event. For example:

```
elif event.key == K_LSHIFT:
    bullet1 = Fire_User()
    bullet1.rect.x = my_ball.rect.x+10
    bullet1.rect.y = my_ball.rect.y
    bulletGroup.add(bullet1)
```

This will make a bullet appear whenever you press `K_LSHIFT`
. I would recommend giving the positions also as the arguments to `__init__` of the `Fire_User()` class. Reduce the increment of the `rect` to see the movement clearly.

As far as removing the bullet is concerned, the `spritecollide` function has an attribute `dokill` for this.

```
spritecollide(sprite, group, dokill, collided = None) -> Sprite_list
```

The dokill argument is a bool. If set to True, all Sprites that collide will be removed from the Group.

Comment: I need the line `pygame.time.delay(1000)` to be able to play my music. Is there a another way?

Comment: Use `pygame.mixer.pre_init()` : [syntax](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.pre_init) to setup `mixer` module before `pygame.mixer.init()` to avoid lag. This way, the `delay` statement can be avoided.